# Do I need a closure inside a DOM event callback?

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

I'm trying to build a jQuery.live like function.
`Helper` is a class that has the `_liveEvent` and `_addEventListener` methods. `Helper._addEventListener` is just a CrossBrowser version of W3C `addEventListener`.

```js
Helper.prototype._liveEvent = function(type, evt, ofunc) {
    var elHand = document;
    type = type.toUpperCase();

    this._addEventListener(elHand, evt, function(me) {
        // Inside here I use the `type` variable.
        // I don't know why but it works.

        for (var el = me.srcElement; el.nodeName !== 'HTML';
            el = el.parentNode)
        {
            if (el.nodeName === type || el.parentNode === null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (el && el.nodeName === type) {
            ofunc.call(el, me);
        }

    });
};
```

I'm running the `Helper._liveEvent` function twice with different types, and it works just fine. I thought that since the `type` variable was set inside the `_liveEvent` context the `_addEventListener` callback could see only the last version of that variable. But it's not the case, it seems to be working fine.

My questions are:

- Why the `_addEventListener` callback can see both versions of the type?
- Does it mean my code is leaking memory?

**UPDATE**

This other example made me understand this better, but I'm not sure I understand it fully yet.

```js
function foo(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 400);

}

// Prints 1, 2, 3
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    foo(i);
}

function bar() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        }, 400);
    }
}

// Prints 4, 4, 4
bar();
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's because a separate closure scope is created for every instance of the anonymous function passed to `_addEventListener()`, each having its own values of `elHand` and `type`.
- It depends on what you mean by "leaking". Every closure prevents objects that it contains from GC'ing. A closure is GC'ed when there are no more objects (say, anonymous functions like yours) referencing it. In this sense, yes, you have a memory leak, as you have no way to remove the added listener (anonymous function) thereby making the associated scope object eligible for GC.

Comment: I think the variable has the correct scope because I called _liveEvent multiple times with multiple inputs, not because I created an anonymous function multiple times.

Comment: It's the same thing here (notice _"each having its own values of `elHand` and `type`"_ suggesting multiple `_liveEvent()` invocations). The listeners added by two successive calls to `_addEventListener()` are two different Function objects.

Comment: look at my second example. The one with timeouts. both foo and bar crate multiple anonymous functions but only one works. The scope is kept by the foo function parameter, not by the annonymous function creation

Comment: Correct, it's a different deal. I might have been unclear that I was only referring to that particular case, not the general one. In the `bar()` function all anonymous functions share one closure scope, which is not the case with `_liveEvent()`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I fully understand yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7919/discussion-between-alexander-pavlov-and-eduardo-cereto)

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, you already are creating a closure. This is why:

```
for( var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    elem.onclick = (function(id) {alert(id);})(i);
}
```

works - calling the anonymous function creates a new closure with `id` set to the *current* value of `i`. (Personally I like to call the argument the same thing as the variable I want to use, so I can think of it as "locking" the value of the variable for that function).

As far as memory leaks go, two calls is not going to cause a leak. If GC works the way I think it does, it removes any closures that have no pointers to them. In particular, when you leave a page, any memory associated with that page is freed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I know how closures work, but this specific case left me in doubt. Because I never execute the anonymous function.